# Unity higher Z position tiles rendered underneath

Tags: unity, rendering, tilemap, isometric

When placing tiles in an isometric tile-map in Unity, I try to place blocks on top using the "Z Position Value" However it looks like higher Z position values get rendered underneath.

[image]

In this picture, the green cubes have a z position of 0 whereas the yellow cubes have a z position of 1. I want the yellow cubes to render on top, but they are underneath. I'm using an Isometric Z as Y tile-map and have the Transparency Sort Axis set to (x=0,y=1,z=-0.26).

Answer (score 3):

Ok I'm going to edit my non-answer for I have just discovered how to fix this !

If you're using URP as I suspect you may be, go to your 2D renderer pipeline file (Renderer 2D Data) and edit the Transparency Sort Mode to Custom Axis and Transparency Sort Axis to (0, 1, [Y dimension of the grid * -0.5] - 0.01).

That will hopefully fix it for you as it did for me.

For EONS I've tried to find those options that were in Project Settings -> Graphics for non-URP projects and remembered that it might just be in the files I had created at the very beginning of my project setup.

[image: 2D renderer file]

[image: In the Inspector]

Comment: for the Z value , how did you find the dimension of grid?